# Extract a float value with a Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

This is my string and I'm working on Python

```
Memoria RAM - 1.5GB 
Memoria RAM - 1 GB
```

This is the regex that I use to extract the value

```
(\d{1,4})((,|.)(\d{1,2})){0,1}
```

The result is:

```
MATCH 1 --> 1.5.5 
MATCH 2 --> 1
```

Of course only the second one is correct. The excepted output is:

```
MATCH 1 --> 1.5
MATCH 2 --> 1
```

Why my regex catch another ".5" ?? How can I fix my regex?

Comment: Why not debug it yourself? See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/oG6gB4/1

Comment: The `.` character in a regex matches **any** character (except `\n`). Your reggae probably should look like this: `(\d+)(,|\.)(\d+)`.

Comment: (\d+)(,|\.)(\d+) can't catch the value without the comma or the dot

Comment: Why not use just [`\d+(?:\.\d+)?`](https://ideone.com/f0h8Mz)? Or `\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*GB)` with `re.findall`?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this example and it works (when using `group(0)`):

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> result = re.search('(\d{1,4})((,|.)(\d{1,2})){0,1}', 'Memoria RAM - 1.5GB')
>>> result.group(0)
'1.5'
```

However if you check `groups()` you'll get:

```
>>> result.groups()
('1', '.5', '.', '5')
```

Why?

You're capturing:

1) The "1" (`(\d{1,4})`);

2) The "." or "," (`(,|.)`, and btw should be `(,|\.)` because `"." - matches any character except a newline` [see more here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) so you should use `\.`);

3) The "5" (`(\d{1,2}`);

4) The.5 (When you use parenthesis around poins 2 and 3 `((,|.)(\d{1,2}))`);

So you should remove the parenthesis in point 4, like this:

```
>>> result = re.search('(\d{1,4})(,|\.)(\d{1,2}){0,1}', 'Memoria RAM - 1.5GB')
>>> result.group(0)
'1.5'
>>> result.groups()
('1', '.', '5')
```

Comment: Probably OP is doing `''.join(result.groups())`.

Comment: @jlnabais that shows the same thing - see the match captures sidebar

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're right I missed it, it should be `(\d{1,4})(,|\.)(\d{1,2}){0,1}` Going to update.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only *capture* each part of the integer/decimal number the way you do with your regex, just make sure the decimal part is optional and use a non-capturing group:

```
(\d{1,4})(?:([,.])(\d{1,2}))?
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hD5xT7/1). I also replaced the `(,|.)` with `[,.]` since I guess your intention was to match either a comma or a dot, not a comma or any character but a newline.

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/yHhIsp):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(\d{1,4})(?:([,.])(\d{1,2}))?')
test_str = "Memoria RAM - 1.5GB \nMemoria RAM - 1 GB"
print ["".join(x) for x in re.findall(p, test_str)]
```

Alternatively, you can just use a regex to match the numbers:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

If you need to match the numbers *only* before *GB*, use a look-ahead:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*GB)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB3jV3/1).

Her is an [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/f0h8Mz):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
test_str = "Memoria RAM - 1.5GB \nMemoria RAM - 1 GB"
print (p.findall(test_str))
# => ['1.5', '1']
```

If you need to match the numbers *only* before *GB*, use a look-ahead:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\s*GB)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB3jV3/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
result = re.findall(r'(?<!\S)\d\.\d+|(?<!\S)\d',st)

(?<!\S) - not preceded by non-space

print(result)

['1.5', '1']
```